# Geth list all javascript commands inside console

Tags: go-ethereum

Need to know every single js console command inside geth like eth.syncing, eth.accounts etc...

Can anyone brief into this?

Comment: Well perhaps you could read the doc? Have a look at ethereum go wiki?

Comment: From the geth console you have web3 v0.20, some docs are at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API, other docs are https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs and https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC. Some of the docs are no longer being updated and for others the only documentation is the source code.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of them here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC and some of them here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs . 
Hope this helps!

I think, currently, there is no other rich documentation as that.